# Script Sends me to search.html? instead of the desired website

Tags: jquery

Alright, so basically, index.html contains a search bar that doesn't do what it's supposed to- when enter is pressed, it should take me to google.com/(gsecode)q=(what i typed), but instead it sends me to index.html? instead of that I want it to use a JQuery Script to trigger a button click. I have looked for solutions but they don't seem to work.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text-box" size="size">
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="(javascriptcode)" name="Google Search">
```

JQuery:

```
document.getElementById("id_of_button").onclick = function() {clickFunction()};

function clickFunction() {
  document.location.href = 'https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' +
  escape(document.getElementById('search-box').value)
}

$("text-box").keyup(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 13){
      $("#submit").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: the id of your input is 'text-box'. and you get the element of 'search-box'

Comment: @WouterdenOuden I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: Do you have a complete example instead of things like `(javascriptcode)` and `"id_of_button"`?  Also, why do you bind the click event *and* call the code inline on the element?  You really only need one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that your IDs was different in the Javascript and HTML.

The second point is that in the keyup function you didn't use the "#" in the selector. If you want to select the element by ID, you need to use the "#" char and the name. If you want to select using class name you need to use "." instead of "#".

And I rewrite your code using only jQuery. I.E.: document.getElementById is the native way in JavaScript to select an element, and I replace to use jQuery selector.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  $("#submit").click(function () {
    
    var url = 'https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' +
           escape($('#text-box').val());
    
    document.location.href = url;
  });


  $("#text-box").keyup(function(event){
      if(event.keyCode === 13){
         $("#submit").click();
      }
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="text-box" size="size">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Google Search">
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what the problem was and what you actually changed?  This looks *very* similar to the original.

Comment: I edited my answer about the problem. Is it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your code is just a loose example or final product, but you have a lot of things wrong here.  I'm just going to post an example that works instead, and you can follow that.

Your ids are not properly named or matching to your jquery selectors.  You have an onclick event that isn't needed

[Heres the fiddle!](http://%20%20%20[1]:%20https://jsfiddle.net/erikrunia/d95p0dsq/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#myButtonId', function() {
    clickFunction();
});

function clickFunction() {
    alert('normally this would run your document location href, but were in jsfiddle so...');
      document.location.href = 'https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' +
  escape($('#mySearchBoxId').val());
}

$('#mySearchBoxId').keyup(function(event){
      if(event.keyCode === 13){
      $("#myButtonId").click();
  }
});
```

and

```
<input type="text" id="mySearchBoxId" size="30">
<input type="submit" id="myButtonId" value="Google Search">
```

Comment: The code doesn't work for me, should I give you a look at my HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure you're even trying. That html you pasted in is not easily readible, but from what I gleaned you didn't even remove the onclick event.  You have my example and the one below, both work.  Please look at them, understand them, and apply it to your code.